# When %,@ and # is used on jsp page in struts2 and what does they imply?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I know the meaning of $ used in case of Expression Language.
But what is the `meaning of %, @ and # characters in value attribute of struts2 tags in jsp`

```
<s:iterator value="sprInstanceData.sprFieldMapDataSetResponse" var="sprFieldMap" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="dbField" value="%{#sprFieldMap.dbField}" theme="simple"/>
            <s:hidden name="packetMappingType" theme="simple" value="%{@com.elitecore.webin.core.constants.PacketMappingType@INCOMING}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="logicalName" value="%{#sprFieldMap.logicalName}" theme="simple"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="defaultValue" value="%{#sprFieldMap.defaultValue}" theme="simple"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="valueMapping" value="%{#sprFieldMap.valueMapping}" theme="simple"/>
        </td>
        <td>
             <img  src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/remove1.jpg'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
/s:iterator>
```

and when they are used?

Comment: Read about OGNL: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/ognl.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks.it solves my problem.Can u mention it in solution.so that it will help other newbies too.